# 301 redirect with .htaccess - redirect if www is included or not

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I've got the following 301 redirect in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^old-site\.com,$ http://www.new-site.com/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

If i visit

> old-site.com

I am redirected correctly.

However, if I visit www.old-site.com, then it doesn't work.
Is there a way of effectively ignoring the `www`

**Edit**

There are several entries like this...

for example:

`www.old-site.com/page-a-242.html` to  `www.new-site.com/page-a`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^old-site\.com,$` – this is nonsense. First of all, what’s the comma good for? And second of all, RewriteRules only match on the _path_ component of a URL, not on the hostname.

Comment: It's nonsense because i used this to generate it ;) http://seo-website-designer.com/HtAccess-301-Redirect-Generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) ignores the domain, so your first rule could be just

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.new-site.com/? [R,L]
```

For the other specific mappings you might use [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap). See [txt: Plain text maps](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt) for details on how to use it.

The drawback with `RewriteMap` is, that it can only be used in the main server config or in a virtual host environment.